# iOS 6.x 7.x Preventing Zoom In Web View When User Selects Pull Down / Picker, Text Field, etc

Tags: ios, webview, zooming

Is there a way to disable "auto zooming" in a Web View when user selects Picker / Text.  Currently scalePagesToFit is YES (and needs to be) and enableMultipleTouch is NO.